# PowerShell: Call function in background with all variables and objects present

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I'm currently trying to call a defined function (which uses declared variables and objects) as background task to alter objects in a PowerShell GUI.

Should be something like that:

```
function CallFunction
{
    #call function in background        
    Start-Job {alterLabel}
}

function alterLabel
{
    $Label.text                      = "Label was altered"
}
```

Is there any possibility to call this function which is already used? So I can't define it as a variable since it would cause a huge redundancy.

Comment: *"I can't define it as a variable since it would cause a huge redundancy."* I don't understand that part - can you elaborate?

Comment: I guess he means it would require repeating a very large amount of code in his script.

Comment: @Tomalak I saw in other posts, that its possible to define the function as a variable and pass it through the Start-Job Command. But I have to access objects (eg. the $Label object) wich are created previous during runtime.

Comment: Use a runspace instead of a job, and then [have a look it this](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using runspacepool:

```
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()

$PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()

$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace

$Runspace.Open()

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({

    function alterLabel
            {
            $Label.text = "Label was altered"
            }

    alterLabel
})

$AsyncObject = $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
$AsyncObject
```

As per the comment, please try this approach. There is an *InitializationScript* parameter in start-job where you can compile the function on prior.

```
$init= function alterLabel
{
    $Label.text  = "Label was altered"
}

Start-Job -InitializationScript $init -ScriptBlock {alterLabel}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
My Problem is that I have to call the function from another part outside the runspace of the script.

Comment: Let me edit the answer and try to give a solution with start-job itself

Comment: To pass the InitializationScript to the Start-Job isn't that good because i need to call the alterLabel function from inside the script.

Should be like:
#### Initialize
function CallFunction
{
alterLabel #as background
}

function alterLabel
{
xxx
}

alterLabel

Comment: I just tried it with your first suggestion. But if i create the runspace I can't refer to the $Label wich is defined outside of the runspace

Comment: You wont be able to refer that . For that you need to use the $asyncobject